# How to delete the contents in List view, maintaining the frame(Windows Forms C# )

Tags: c#, listview, columnheader

I've just started to learn basic programming and got an assignment to program a search box.

The problem I have is that the clear button clears the whole thing in the list view box including column headers. I want just the printed contents gone, and those column headers to remain. Here's my code.

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;

        func = (controls) =>
        {
            foreach (Control control in controls)
                if (control is ListView)
                    (control as ListView).Clear();
                else
                    func(control.Controls);
        };

        func(Controls);
    }
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: On the side note, you could have done this without looping thru all the controls on the form and simply doing `listivewName..Items.Clear()`

Comment: Thank you for your amazing help! I tried and it worked all thanks to your help. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Items.Clear();

Like this :  `listview.Items.Clear();`

Hope this works :)

Comment: Thanks for the real quick answer! Can you tell me if I have to add it to the code or replace the code I made? If I have to add it to the code, where?

Comment: Wonderful, I tried both and it worked! I really appreciate your invaluable help! Have a nice Day.

Comment: @LFLJM sure :) you to.